# sudo command is asking user's password

Tags: pi-2, sudo, password

I changed the default username using usermod.
and now whenever I type a sudo command it requires a password.
I do it only when it is the first time I type sudo.
further it does not require any password.
I do not understand it.

Comment: What is your actual issue or question?

Comment: This is a general *nix question, it is not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with changing the user name, it's default `sudo` behaviour. `sudo` caches your credentials so you don't get asked if you do another `sudo` within a short range of time (15 minutes is default). If you don't enter another `sudo` command for 15 minutes, you'll get prompted again. Or do `sudo -k` to reset the credentials immediately.

Comment: fixed with visudo

Answer (score 0):

fixed with visudo
line 
pi ALL=(All) NOPASSWD:ALL
change : pi --> nex $USER
thanks